# Read millions of SQS message and persist in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-emr, amazon-aurora

I have million of SQS message coming on daily basis. Currently we are reading same from various poller machines and writing same in RDBMS (Aurora PostgreSQL). Architecture has two flaw:

1. It is taking more than 10 hours to process all SQS messages. We are targeting 2-3 hours for same.
2. SQS messages are coming from a job. It is not continuous activity. Maintaining poller machines 24 hours is costing us.

We have already configured SQS *NumberOfPollers* to 20 and *MessageFetchSize* to 10.

My questions are:

1. Apart from NumberOfPollers and MessageFetchSize, is there any other SQS configuration parameter we can use to speed the process?
2. How to calculate correct value of NumberOfPollers and MessageFetchSize? We are just doing try and error in this.
3. Can we utilize EMR-Spark to do allocate machine on demand and run poller and terminate it after execution, so that we need not to maintain machine 24x7?
4. Any other suggestion/ways to achieve same

Comment: Have you analyzed where the time is spent? As in "processing a batch of messages takes X milliseconds, of which Y is spent reading from SQS and Z is spent writing to Postgres"? If yes, please put those numbers in your question. If not, do this and _then_ put those numbers in your question.

Comment: @kdgregory Thanks for reply. we are doing same. I will update post once I get stat